# Blocked messages not going through on iPhone but showing as read on Macbook

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

EDIT: I just tested with 2 more people. They blocked me but this time on my phone, it shows blue and delivered, though it never goes through to their phone. However, it did go through on their other Apple devices even though I am clearly blocked.

A contact of mine blocked me, but I'm experiencing strange behaviors with messages and delivery status. We both have iPhones with the latest iOS update and are using Messages. We both have SMS enabled as a fallback and read receipts on.

Wednesday in the middle of a conversation, my message didn't go through. it stayed blue, then 5 minutes later turned green and said sent as SMS. I freaked out of course and it was their bed time, so I didn't know if they got it and didn't reply or didn't get it. A few hours later I sent another message to see if it was just a fluke. On my phone where I sent it from, it again said sent as text message and was green. I opened my laptop and saw that the message was showing as delivered there. However, I found posts online saying it's a bug and would not be delivered if I was blocked.

Hours later to my surprise, the status turned to read with a time stamp. I cannot find ANY information about false read receipts. Everything I've seen says it cannot possibly say read if indeed it was not delivered in the first place. To add to my confusion, I sent another message to test later that day and it went through normally on my phone, and the next morning showed as read with a time stamp. Days later I sent a "checking in to see if you're OK" message from my phone. Again it turned green and sent as a text. But on my laptop, once again it showed delivered, and hours later read with a time stamp.

I have no idea what's going on. Is it possible for a read receipt to somehow show up, more than once, if it was never even delivered? Obviously there's a bug here but I'd love to have peace of mind that the messages got delivered and read. I don't plan to send any more, I'm just trying to figure out what happened.